# Nothing is showing in Angular View

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Working on Web App.I am using Laravel as Back End and Angular for Frond end.When i 
open my app it throws the below error

> GET http://localhost/ngresulty/public/ 404 (Not Found)

Plus nothing is displayed in the view file.

**App.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['mainCtrl', 'myAppService']);
```

**appService.js**

```
angular.module('myAppService', [])

    .factory('Result', function($http) {

        return {
            get : function() {
                return $http.get('http://localhost/ngresulty/public/result');
            },
            show : function(id) {
                return $http.get('api/result/' + id);
            },
            save : function(resultData) {
                return $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'api/result',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                    data: $.param(resultData)
                });
            },
            destroy : function(id) {
                return $http.delete('api/result/' + id);
            }
        }

    });
```

**MainCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('mainCtrl', [])

    .controller('mainController', function($scope, $http, Result) {
        // object to hold all the data for the new comment form
        $scope.resultData = {};

        // loading variable to show the spinning loading icon
        $scope.loading = true;

        // get all the comments first and bind it to the $scope.comments object
        Result.get()
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.students = data;
                $scope.loading = false;
            });


        // function to handle submitting the form
        $scope.submitResult = function() {
            $scope.loading = true;

            // save the comment. pass in comment data from the form
            Result.save($scope.resultData)
                .success(function(data) {
                    $scope.resultData = {};
                    // if successful, we'll need to refresh the comment list
                    Result.get()
                        .success(function(getData) {
                            $scope.students = getData;
                            $scope.loading = false;
                        });

                })
                .error(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
        };

        // function to handle deleting a comment
        $scope.deleteResult = function(id) {
            $scope.loading = true; 

            Result.destroy(id)
                .success(function(data) {

                    // if successful, we'll need to refresh the comment list
                    Result.get()
                        .success(function(getData) {
                            $scope.students = getData;
                            $scope.loading = false;
                        });

                });
        };

    });
```

**View / Results.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')


<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">All Students Results Record</div>
                <label>Search: <input ng-model="searchText"></label>



                <div class="panel-body">

                    <input type="text" ng-model="search">

                    <table class="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                <th>Roll No</th>
                                <th>Student Name</th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody ng-hide="loading" ng-repeat="student in students | filter:searchText">
                                    <td>@{{ student.rollno }}</td>
                                    <td>@{{ student.name }}</td>
                            </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Action(s)</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <center><a type="submit" href="/ngresulty/public/result/create" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Add New Result(s)</a></center>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    {!! Html::script('app/controllers/mainCtrl.js'); !!}
    {!! Html::script('app/services/myAppService.js'); !!}
    {!! Html::script('app/app.js'); !!}

@endsection
```

**Config**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Environment
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value determines the "environment" your application is currently
    | running in. This may determine how you prefer to configure various
    | services your application utilizes. Set this in your ".env" file.
    |
    */

    'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Debug Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
    | stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
    | application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
    |
    */

    'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
    | the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
    | your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
    |
    */

    'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Timezone
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
    | will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
    | ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
    |
    */

    'timezone' => 'UTC',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Locale Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
    | by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
    | to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
    |
    */

    'locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Fallback Locale
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The fallback locale determines the locale to use when the current one
    | is not available. You may change the value to correspond to any of
    | the language folders that are provided through your application.
    |
    */

    'fallback_locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Encryption Key
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
    | to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
    | will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an application!
    |
    */

    'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Logging Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the log settings for your application. Out of
    | the box, Laravel uses the Monolog PHP logging library. This gives
    | you a variety of powerful log handlers / formatters to utilize.
    |
    | Available Settings: "single", "daily", "syslog", "errorlog"
    |
    */

    'log' => env('APP_LOG', 'single'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Autoloaded Service Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The service providers listed here will be automatically loaded on the
    | request to your application. Feel free to add your own services to
    | this array to grant expanded functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
        Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
        Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,
        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Aliases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
    | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
    | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
    |
    */

    'aliases' => [

        'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
        'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
        'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
        'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
        'Cookie' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
        'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
        'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
        'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
        'Event' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
        'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
        'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
        'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
        'Lang' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
        'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
        'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
        'Password' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
        'Queue' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
        'Redirect' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
        'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
        'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
        'Response' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
        'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
        'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
        'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
        'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
        'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
        'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
        'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
        'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
        'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
        'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class,
    ],

];
```

Comment: add your Laravel code and config

Comment: added @JahirulIslamBhuiyan

Comment: You may wish to add this code to jsfiddle or plunker.  You would probably get more responses.

Comment: Ok let me add it @Dale

Comment: @Dale but how to add laravel API over there , i am getting data from laravel in JSON format and then displaying via angular in view.

Comment: I see, so if you know that your API works just stub in the data for the sake of finding the solution.  Can you make a bare call to your service an have it return a JSON string? .. if so ... just stub it in.

Comment: this error doesn't appear to relate to javascript or angularjs at all.  A 404 error for the URL http://localhost/ngresulty/public/ is an indication that there is no default document in that directory on the server, which would happen long before angular or javascript would get involved.

Comment: I agree.  It seems if you can't get to your page you would need to solve that solution first.  That might be the first problem.  Also, if this is just AngularJS, you could just make it an HTML page and not even use PHP.  Later on after you get the page going if you wish to use PHP, then add it.

Comment: As it goes for angular you have some issues. If i got it right, your app has 1 controller and 1 service. Your App.js must look like this
`var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);` since the service and the controller are part of your module.
Also to make an angular module component you  must use
`angular.module('myApp')` in order to fetch the module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says :

```
GET http://localhost/ngresulty/public/ 404 (Not Found)
```

There is something wrong in your laravel routes,Check that first and make sure `http://localhost/ngresulty/public/` is loading .

Moreover this error has no connection with `angularjs` at all. This indicates that there is no route set for the `URL` you are trying to get.

Comment: @WebEngineer : Glad I could help..!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a angular or js problem, you should check your laravel router and your local webserver(wamp/xamp?)